# How to remove item from an array on condition using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an an array which is mentioned below. I would like to remove an item from the array which has empty property value using JavaScript.

**Actual array:**

```
[
    {
        "href":"/client",
        "methods":[]
    },
    {
        "href":"/home",
        "methods":
            {
                "type1":"GET",
                "type2":"POST",
            }
    },
    {
        "href":"/about",
        "methods":[]
    },
    {
        "href":"/contact",
        "methods":
            {
                "type1":"GET",
                "type2":"POST",
            }
    }
]
```

**Expecting result:**

```
[
    {
        "href":"/home",
        "methods":
            {
                "type1":"GET",
                "type2":"POST",
            }
    },
    {
        "href":"/contact",
        "methods":
            {
                "type1":"GET",
                "type2":"POST",
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: So, remove it when `methods` is an empty array?

Comment: That is an array of objects, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of methods, you can easily walk the object and then call delete on the keys with values that are empty.... or empty arrays.  I expanded the answer to cover not only keys of methods where an array is empty, but all keys with what i would define as empty contents.

```
var l = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
  var keys = Object.keys(l[i]);
  for ( var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
    var value = keys[j];
    // In your use case, you are only doing arrays so i coded it as such.
    if (value.length == 0){
      delete l[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to expand it to cover a variety of cases such as empty string, empty arrays, empty maps, or null values you can defined a function to do that.

```
function isValueDeletable(value){
  if (value == null) return true;
  if (value == "") return true;
  if (value instanceof Array && value.length == 0) return true;
  if (value instanceof Map && Object.keys(value).length == 0) return true;
  return false;
}
```

and apply that instead of the value.length == 0;

```
if (isValueDeletable(value)){ delete l[i][j]; }
```

Then l is modified to remove all keys with empty values.

Answer (score 2):

This is the job for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). however filter does not modify the existing array so you need to assign it to a different array/overwrite the current variable

```
a = a.filter(item => Object.keys(item.methods).length > 0)
```

Comment: The above syntax does not work in IE due to arrow function. Can u help me to resolve this issue in IE..

Comment: If you click on the filter link above you'll see a pretty straight forward example on how this can be used with traditional function calls. You just need to replace the arrow function with traditional function syntax.

function(item){ return Object.keys(item.methods).length > 0; }

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the object array and filter based on `methods` property length.

```
var obj = [...];
obj = obj.filter((val) => val.methods && val.methods.length !== 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

enter var json = {};

var key = "giveitakeyvalue";

json[key] = null;

delete json[key];